# Undercarriage corrosion when move away from states with snow

Tags: rust, corrosion

We bought a car in a state that has a lot of snow. We then moved to a state where it never snows. A letter from my car manufacturer says that we can get a free anti-corrosion material applied since they did not do it properly at the factory.

Question: would doing it be more beneficial than just taking the car through an under-carriage car wash at a gas station once? Since they don't use salt on roads here.

Comment: If it's free, why not? What if you travel through snowy areas, extended stay in snowy areas, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always good to oil the underneath regardless if there is salt on the roads or not. You will preserve the metal and increase the life of your vehicle. Once rust starts, it spreads like cancer.

That being said, I would wash the underside and then get it undercoated. They should be washing the vehicle before they spray.

Comment: Thanks, took it in. They did not wash it, and they broke the side mirror mechanism... isn't that a more realistic outcome than the ones predicted!